# Can someone explain this verse in the Brahmavaivart Purana?

Tags: puranas, krishna, apsaras, brahma-vaivarta-purana, devatas

Do the gods "use" the apsarās in a sexual way or does this mean something else?

Brahmavaivart Purana, Krishna Janma Khanda, 32.55

[Source](https://archive.org/details/357106450BrahmavaivartaPurana2SanskritTextWithEnglishTranslationPdf/357106450-Brahmavaivarta-Purana-2-Sanskrit-text-with-English-translation-pdf/page/n305/mode/1up?view=theater)

*"Some of the ladies becomes whores and earn their living by selling away their body. **I am an apsarā of the heaven and am used by the gods in the heaven** and am quite respectable"*

Comment: Apasaras are created from Rajas and hence they are the embodiment of lust and physical beauty. They are also known as the "celestial prostitutes".

Comment: @Rickross They aren't "prostitutes" technically because they aren't being *bought* with cash. Apsaras don't have financial transactions with anyone. They are there for sex however.

Comment: Even though money is not involved since they do it with numerous males they can be called that for that reason @Ikshvaku

Comment: @Rickross Word for that is "whore" or "svairini" in Sanskrit.

Comment: Oh so you have problem with my choice of word? @Ikshvaku

Comment: @Rickross Yes, I know what you mean, but I'm just saying prostitute gives the wrong impression that they are bought.